# Is it clear what "it" is referring to in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns, syntactic-analysis

> It'd been so long since I last saw his smile **it** came like a sun.

I'm not sure whether it's clear what the bolded **it** is referring to. If so, can I write it like that? Is it grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

First let's dispose of the *it* at the beginning of the sentence—the one embedded in *It'd*:

> It'd been so long since I last saw his smile it came like a sun.

As John Lawler points out in connection with a similarly functioning *it* in a [different sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263530/what-do-the-pronouns-indicate/263544#263544), this first *it* is a "dummy non-referential pronoun inserted by Extraposition." In the present instance, the first *it* is the subject of "[ha]d been"; having done its job there, the first *it* drops out of the picture as we move forward in the sentence.

The second *it* is the one that the OP focuses on. The only noun preceding the occurrence of this second *it* in the sentence is *smile*—and therefore *smile* must be the intended referent of the *it*.

The only stumbling block to immediate apprehension of this fact is the author's use of an implied (rather than explicit) *that* between *smile* and *it*:

> It'd been so long since I last saw his smile [that] it came like a sun.

Fluent English speakers are so familiar with this particular type of omission that they scarcely notice it. When we replace the second *it* with its full referent ("his smile"), however, we become more aware of the absent *that*:

> It'd been so long since I last saw his smile [that] his smile came like a sun.

The simile here is that the person's smile is as welcome and warm and bright as the sun. Maybe his teeth are very white and dazzle the narrator.

Answer (score 0):

> He is so kind to his fellow people that people started to consider him like a saint.

The meaning of this sentence is **He is kind to such a degree that people started to consider him like a saint**

If **that** is omitted, a comma generally come in that place.

In your quoted sentence the use of ***That*** is optional. Your quoted sentence in your question bear the same pattern/construction like that of my quoted sentence.

In your quoted sentence ***That*** was omitted. And the ***it*** you marked bold clearly refers to the smile. But that **it** is not optional, in my opinion and I'd probably use a comma before **it**.

Comment: But if *that* is omitted, I'd probably use a comma after *smile*.

Comment: Possibly because the question doesn't ask about the absence of *that,* but the use of *it*. Whereas your question majors on *that* and barely mentions *it.* It may be that someone gave up reading before the last sentence, thinking that *it* wasn't going to feature at all.